# Select for update not working

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jboss

My following native query is not working:

```
Query createNativeQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
   "select id from cscache where id=? for update ");
```

Environment Details:

1. Mysql 5.6
2. Jboss 5.1
3. JPA 1.0

Error:

> 2014-12-12 10:20:14,581 WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter]
>
> SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000   (http-0.0.0.0-8543-3:)
>
> 2014-12-12 10:20:14,581 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter]
>       You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit 2' at line 1 (http-0.0.0.0-8543-3:)

Comment: Where is the code that has the query with `limit 2`?

Comment: This the only code it does not have limit 2. My guess is Hibernate MySQL dialect does not supports select for update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't actually done a for update in hibernate, but I believe you can (and should?) do it on the Session or query object. Why not let hibernate do it instead of executing a native query?
According to the documentation on locking ([Chapter 5: Locking](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html), you can set the lock mode on either the session or the query.

```
Cscache  cscache  = (Cscache )session.get( Cscache.class, id, LockOptions.UPGRADE );
```

Specifying the LockOptions should result in a SELECT ... FOR UPDATE being executed.

Answer (score 5):

For Update basically puts a lock on rows, to achieve the same using JPA you need to use [Lock Modes](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjiu.html). To set the lock, you can use EntityManager or TypeQuery and use LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE.

Refer [this article](http://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2013/08/01/doing-select-for-update-in-jpa/)

Comment: I am having JPA 1.0 where LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE is not available

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with JPA specifically, but it appears you're not telling it what the value of `?` is.  Check out [setParameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Query.html).

Comment: I have this in next line  createNativeQuery.setParameter(1, 19)

Comment: Right, but shouldn't it be `?1` instead of `?`?

Comment: It is working fine for select id from cscache where id=?  but if you give for update it does not works