# Spring data jpa SELECT ... FOR UPDATE Query not working with @query

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, db2

I am trying to use FOR UPDATE with SELECT in Spring Data Jpa Repository.

Below query doesn't give error while running it on Database console. 
But in Spring Data JPA throws an exception, it is not able to recognize token for in below query.
Intentionally using Braces instead of greater and smaller than symbol in first line of code as it is hiding data inside those tags while trying to post question

```
public interface XRepository extends JpaRepository(X, String) {
@Query(value = "SELECT UPDATE t FROM X t WHERE t.a = ?1 AND t.b = ?2 FOR UPDATE")
X findByAAndB(String a, String b);
}
```

Stack trace:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: FOR near line 1, column 141 IT is giving error for FOR in Query
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1679) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:294) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy114.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:86) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 67 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: 
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:288) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:187) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1894) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 74 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at the following answer for a question similar to yours: [Select for update not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27447507/6912996)

Here is what it says:

> For Update basically puts a lock on rows, to achieve the same using JPA you need to use Lock Modes. To set the lock, you can use EntityManager or TypeQuery and use LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE.
>
> Refer [this article](https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2013/08/01/doing-select-for-update-in-jpa/)

Comment: Is there something in spring data jpa that can handle locks rather than specifying the locks on own? Regular for update does works fine on dba console may be something we can do it in jpa as well when the query is fired with For Update it will automatically handle locking and unlocking.. Thanks

Comment: Read this article [jpa-pessimistic-locking](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pessimistic-locking), I believe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I used below annotation and it worked: @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)  X findByAAndB(String a, String b); }

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that it is **not** the `FOR` token that is causing the trouble here.

I think that "SELECT **UPDATE t** FROM X **t**" is invalid SQL syntax.